# Using list defined in one function in another function. Python 2.7

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, tkinter

I have a problem with the following code. Now I'm very new to programming in general, and most of the code is copied off the internet, and I adjusted it so it would work the way I want it to. So if there is no easy way of solving it, that's ok. Maybe you can just point out some topics of programming or python, that I should read about.

I try to explain it anyways. I have defined the function query(), that makes some changes to sqlite databases. The input is a list. That function works just fine if I use it just by itself.

Now I'm trying to have an Interface, where I can define, what should be inside that list, depending on what checkboxes are checked. Then I want to execute the function with that specific list, when I press a button. The checkboxes are generated just fine, the button, too. Also, when I check or uncheck the buttons, it updates the list just fine, and it shows the new updated list in the interpreter.

The problem is, that the button does not work:
1. It doesn't use the new updated list, instead it uses an empty list ()
2. When I input a predefined list, that is not empty, it automatically runs query() without me even clicking the button.

I may not have explained this well, but I hope you understand what my problem is.

Thanks for the help

`

```
def chkbox_checked():
    for ix, item in enumerate(cb):
        opt[ix]=(cb_v[ix].get())
    print opt

def query(opt):
    import sqlite3
    connection = sqlite3.connect("gather.sqlite")
    cursor1 = connection.cursor()

    cursor1.execute('Drop table IF EXISTS matches')
    cursor1.execute('CREATE TABLE matches(date TEXT, team1 TEXT, team2 TEXT, league TEXT)')
    cursor1.execute('DELETE FROM "main"."matches"')

    for i in range(0, len(opt)):
        a=opt[i]
        cursor1.execute('INSERT INTO matches (date, team1, team2, league) SELECT * FROM gather WHERE team1=? or team2=? or league=?', (a,a,a,))

    cursor1.execute('Drop table IF EXISTS matchessorted')
    cursor1.execute('CREATE TABLE matchessorted(date TEXT, team1 TEXT, team2 TEXT, league TEXT)')
    cursor1.execute('DELETE FROM "main"."matchessorted"')
    cursor1.execute('INSERT INTO matchessorted (date, team1, team2, league) SELECT * FROM matches ORDER BY date')

    connection.commit()





import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *

opt = []

root = tk.Tk()
mylist = [
'name1',
'name2',
'name3'
]
cb = []
cb_v = []
for ix, text in enumerate(mylist):
    cb_v.append(tk.StringVar())
    off_value=0
    cb.append(tk.Checkbutton(root, text=text, onvalue=text,offvalue=off_value,
                             variable=cb_v[ix],
                             command=chkbox_checked))
    cb[ix].grid(row=ix, column=0, sticky='w')
    opt.append(off_value)
    cb[-1].deselect()


label = tk.Label(root, width=20)
label.grid(row=ix+1, column=0, sticky='w')


button1 = Button(root, text = "Calculate", command = query(opt))
button1.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=W)


root.mainloop()
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of points about how to structure your code: You need to write a function that populates the list based on your selection. It can return a list call 'options' and when you want to execute the code inside the query, you call the function that constructs the options list. The query function will have a statement like this:

```
 options = get_options() #assuming the function that populates the options is called get_options
```

and then you execute the query function's code.

Comment: Isn't chkbox_checked() populating the list?

So should this work?

options = chkbox_checked

and then 

query(options)

?

Answer (score 0):

```
button1 = Button(root, text = "Calculate", command = query(opt))
```

This calls query(opt) immediately, before you create your Button, and passes the result of that call (None) to the Button constructor as the command argument. What you really want is a function that, when called, executes query(opt). Something like this:

```
def calculate_clicked():
    query(opt)
button1 = Button(root, text = "Calculate", command = calculate_clicked)
```

or this:

```
button1 = Button(root, text = "Calculate", command = lambda : query(opt))
```